# can i open my own dialog box within javascript and pass value object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-5

I want to run this dialog box code and pass value object to it. when click this link value object is passed correctly. If there any way to call my div ="#myModel" and pass value to it.

```
  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">


        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;' data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>
                <h4 class="modal-title">BASL  Officers  Details {{ $basl_officer }} </h4>
            </div>



            <!-- text input -->
            <div class="modal-body">

                {!! Form::label('o_code', 'Officers Code: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_code','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


                {!! Form::label('o_name', 'Officers Name: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_name','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            function showData(x) {
            // console.log(x);
                   alert('You clicked the top text' + x['code']);

                    $("#myModal").dialog({
                          autoOpen: true

                    });
            }

</script>
```

please kindly expect some help as soon as possible.this all code in same page.

////////////////////full code///////////////////////////////////////////

```
  @extends('layouts.app')

@section('slide_bar')
@include('layouts.master_entry_slide_bar')
@endsection

@section('content')




<section class="content-header">
    <h1>BASL  Officers  <small>page </small></h1>
</section>


<br/>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="gap">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <col width='auto'>
                        <col width='auto'>
                        <col width='100'>

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>BASL Officers Code</th>
                                <th>BASL Officers Name</th>
                                <th><p id='buttons'> <a href="{{ route('basl_officers_page.create')}}" class="btn btn-success"> <strong> Add New Officers &nbsp </strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </a> </p></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                  

                            @foreach ($basl_officers as $basl_officer)
                            <tr >
                                <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{ $basl_officer->code }} </a></td>        
                                <td><a href="#" onClick="showData({{ json_encode($basl_officer) }})">{{ $basl_officer->officerName }} </a></td>        
                                <td align='center'>
                                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['basl_officers_page.destroy',$basl_officer->id]]) !!}
                                    <a href="{{route('basl_officers_page.edit',$basl_officer->id)}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a> &nbsp &nbsp
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button> 
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </td> 
                            </tr>


                            @endforeach

                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>BASL Officers Code</th>
                                <th>BASL Officers Name</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.row -->

</section><!-- /.content -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">


        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;' data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>
                <h4 class="modal-title">BASL  Officers  Details {{ $basl_officer }} </h4>
            </div>



            <!-- text input -->
            <div class="modal-body">

                {!! Form::label('o_code', 'Officers Code: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_code','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


                {!! Form::label('o_name', 'Officers Name: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('officers_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'officers_name','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<script>
            var name = document.getElementById("master_entry");
            document.getElementById("master_entry").className = "active";
            var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("bd_menu");
            document.getElementById("bd_menu").className = "active";
            var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("bd_submenu1");
            document.getElementById("bd_submenu1").className = "active";</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            function showData(x) {

                $("#myModal").dialog({
                    autoOpen: true
               });
            }

</script>




@endsection
```

Comment: this should be ok what is the problem?

Comment: @Pekka didn't come dialog box .:-( when i click link didn't give any response.when i put this code.whiout this part '$("#myModal").dialog({
                          autoOpen: true
                          data : x;
                    });
           ' show alert box.

Comment: seem to be mixing bootsrtrap html and jQuery UI dialog script. What library resources are loaded in page? What errors do you get in console?

Comment: And where is `showData()` called from? Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl  <td><a href="#" onClick="showData({{ json_encode($basl_officer) }})" data-object-type="{{ json_encode($basl_officer) }}">{{ $basl_officer->officerName }} </a></td> this is show data calling link.

Comment: please update question with that relevant code so it is readable by all. Don't dump code in comment blocks

Comment: @charlietfl , sir i added all code. and there are some syntax error in 'data : x' so i remove that code , now there are no error in console. when I click link stuck all site. :-(